# Does Mergesort Have Swaps?

Tags: sorting, mergesort

Title says it all. So my understanding of merge sort is that we iterate through two lists and insert items into a third list. By making sure we compare items between the first two lists, we can merge the lists in an ordered form in the third list. However, I don't see any swaps happening. I only see comparisons and then simply writing data. Does mergesort technically not have swaps?

Comment: If by 'swap' you mean "reading two values in memory and writing them in reverse order in the same two locations", then no.   If you mean it in the the more usual sense "the relative order of two elements are reversed in the output", then yes.

Comment: A standard merge sort treats an array of size n as n sub-arrays of size 1 (bottom up starts this way, top down gets to this point before any merging starts) and only uses a merge operation to merge sub-arrays.. As an option, on the first pass, even and odd elements could be swapped in place. Another variation would separate an array of size n into n/k sub-arrays of size k and use some type of swap or insertion type sort on the sub-arrays of size k.

Answer (score 1):

The sort answer is that merge sort does not have swaps, or better stated is that it does not need swaps. We can create a temporary array that will be returned as the sum of the lengths of the arrays being merged in order. We can see this when merge sort breaks them down into singlets. When you are at the level of singlets, we had to be passed in by a longer array so we did not swap anything. Additionally, at the level of singlets, we only need to do one comparison and then generate an array of length 2 and place them in order. When this array is meet with another array, we obtain the length of both to build an array of their sum and then walk down both arrays doing comparisons to place them in order into this new array. Again, we see that no new swaps are needed to do this action and by the beauty of recursion, this process will follow the same until we have one complete sorted array. Since the singlets case and the general case of merging 2 arrays does not need swaps and only comparisons, then the entire algorithm does not need swaps to sort the array. 
So in conclusion, merge sort technically does not have swaps.

Hope this help - jason